# Output not displaying zeros in the beginning of binary conversions

Tags: java, binary, output

I tried searching for answers to this specific question, I could see formatting options and how to pad zeros to the left but my output cannot have decimal space designated zeros but only the zeros from the conversion result. For example if I convert 45 to binary it should display 00101101 but it omits the first two zeros, obviously, and displays 101101. If I format the output it displays extra or less zeros based on the format specifications. I am a beginner and not very good at JAVA. All help is appreciated. Here is the part of code specific to my question:

```
public class DecimalToBinary {
public String toBinary(int b) {
    if (b==0) {
        return "0";
        }
        String binary = "";
        while (b > 0 && b < 256) {
            int rem = b % 2;
            binary = rem + binary;
            b = b / 2;
        }
    return binary;
}
```

//MAIN:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Choice;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalToBinary convertD2B = new DecimalToBinary();
    BinaryToDecimal convertB2D = new BinaryToDecimal();
    do{
    System.out.println("Hello! What would you like to do today? Please enter 1, 2, or 3 based on the following: "+"\n"+
    "1. Convert Decimal to Binary"+"\n"+"2. Convert Binary to Decimal"+"\n"+"3. Exit");
    Choice = input.nextInt();
    if(Choice==1){
        System.out.println("Enter a Decimal Number between 0 to 255: ");
        int decimalNumber = input.nextInt();
        if(decimalNumber<256)
            {String output = convertD2B.toBinary(decimalNumber);
            System.out.println("The Binary equivalent of "+decimalNumber+" is: "+output);
            }
        else
            {System.out.println("Please start over and enter a number between 0 and 255.");}
    }
```

Comment: Why should it print "00101101" ? Do you want your result to be always 8-bit long?

Comment: Yes precisely, need the output to be 8 bit long. :)

Comment: If `output` is a string then you could concatenate some `"0"`'s to it before printing.

Comment: @jkdev My question may be dumb but would that work considering results vary based on the input number?

Comment: You'd have to measure the length of the string, so you know how many zeros to prepend.  As I understand it, in this case the binary numbers range from `0` (which, as a string, is 1 character long, so you'd need to prepend seven zeros) to `11111111` (which, as a string, is 8 characters long, so you wouldn't have to prepend anything). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `printf` to make a formated output. This line for example produces an output of the parameter value `2` consisting of 5 digits. It will fill up with leading 0's if neccessary.

```
System.out.printf("%05d", 2);  // output is 00002
```

But this will only work with decimals and not with strings. But you can use this if you calc the difference manually and put in a `0` as paramter.

```
System.out.printf("The Binary equivalent of "+decimalNumber+" is: %0" + (8 - output.length()) + "d%s\n", 0, output);
```

Comment: ArcticLord, nailed it my friend, exactly what I wanted. Cheers. :)
Thank you everybody for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `output` is a string then you could put some zeros in front of it to it before printing.

Just measure the length of `output` and prepend the `"0"` string to it, `8 - length` times.

Comment: That's a great suggestion but is there no way to format the output to always have 8 characters without adding an entire additional process? Another way I thought of was to specify an output of 8 zeros and replace the zeros from the right with the corresponding numbers from the result, but again, I don't want that. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if there's another way. You could write a function to "pretty print" binary numbers, and just call that function whenever you need it. Or maybe someone already wrote a library for that kind of thing... maybe try a GitHub search for "Java printing library" or something similar?